# grep rows in R based on single column

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
             T0h T0.25h T0.5h T1h
NM_001001130  68     95    56  43
NM_001001144   0      1     4   0
NM_001001152  79    129    52  50
NM_001001160   1      1     2   0
NM_001001176   0      0     0   0
NM_001001177   1      3     2   3
```

I want to keep the rows where the value in column 1 (T0h) is smaller than 10. 
I have tried the function but it didn't really work.
Any suggestion on a simple grep line in R?

Comment: The request for a grep solution seems rather odd (an may be what generated the close votes.)  You want a mathematical comparison so a `?Comparison` operator would seem more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> df[df$T0h<10, ]
             T0h T0.25h T0.5h T1h
NM_001001144   0      1     4   0
NM_001001160   1      1     2   0
NM_001001176   0      0     0   0
NM_001001177   1      3     2   3
```

Or using `subset`

```
> subset(df, T0h <10)
```